Frame freezes, but can still type & open new frame
I am running Emacs 29.3, installed via brew, on MacOS 14.4. Often (and this may have happened with earlier versions of both Emacs and MacOS; not sure), the current frame freezes. If this happens, nothing whatsoever makes it unfreeze (specifically, C-g keyboard-quit has no effect).
I am not usually doing anything special, i.e. it is not usually an interactive M-! shell-command or a huge file or something along those lines.
It could be that my fingers slipped or that I was typing too fast - it does not happen if I just let the frame sit there alone. Basically, I'm hacking happily, and suddenly the frame just stops responding.
The frame obviously still receives my keyboard input, although it shows none of it, because if I enter C-x 5 2 make-frame-command), a new frame opens, and this responds as usual. Then I close the original frame (either by C-x 5 0 delete-frame or by clicking the corresponding decoration) and everything is fine.
Can you think of an explanation or reason for this behaviour? Do you know of some keyboard combo which could cause this (similar to M-! with a long-running subcommand), which my fingers might stumble over, accidentally? E.g., is there some regular emacs command to freeze the frame (similar to how C-s and C-q work as flow control in Unix terminals)?
Otherwise, can you advise on how to possibly debug this further?

Confirmed using this build https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-29.3-universal.dmg It seems to happen most often to me during typing. I've disabled completion via corfu for now to see if that's a culprit tickling a latent Emacs bug.

I have a similar (or identical) problem.
There seems to be a correlation with setting the mark.
I have the CapsLock key set to be a Control key, so perhaps CapsLock-Space has something to do with it?

This build https://github.com/jimeh/emacs-builds/releases/tag/Emacs-29.4 is way better and, so far, has no freezes and is about 10x faster than https://emacsformacosx.com/

Hey... I completely forgot about my original issue since it did not happen for quite a long while now. I do not remember when I had the last time it happens. OTOH in the meantime I also switched to a new M3 MBP (from an 2019 Intel MBP I had before), and also we had a few major new MacOS releases since April. I am still on the emacsformacosx 29.3 release right now (installed via brew).
